# (C program) Line of sight through a ring at an inclination : calculating the path length along my line of sight from sources around this ring

Tags: c, algorithm, 3d, geometry, conditional-statements

I have a uniform ring inclined at an angle along my line of sight. The dimensions of the ring are :

```
9.5 : inner radius
10.5 : outer radius
-3 to 3 : height of the ring
```

There are  a number of sources spread across the ring and I am trying to calculate if a line drawn from each source passes through this ring along my direction or not. If it passes through the ring, how much path length will it exhibit going through this ring (e.g. passing twice through the ring or once or never).

I have the direction vectors from each source towards my line of sight and I am using a simple vector addition to increment along my direction.

The problem with my program :

It checks only if the path length is less than the outer radius of the ring or not. How can I check that my source passes through both the rings or not ?

Any help will be greatly appreciated !!

My program :

```
/********************************************************************
xn, yn, zn : coordinates of the sources

ns_ux, ns_uy, ns_uz : unit vectors for these sources

ns : distance of a source from the sun

int_val : path length

********************************************************************/
int main(){
    FILE *fp=NULL;
    fp=fopen("Av_path.txt","w");  

    int k,number=9;
    float step=0.02;
    float ns_ux[number],ns_uy[number],ns_uz[number],xn[number], yn[number],zn[number],l[number],b[number],ns[number],int_val,x_comp,y_comp,z_comp,radial;

    FILE* val= NULL;
    val=fopen("novae_uniform_unitvectors.txt", "r");
    for(k=0;k<=(number-1);k++){
        fscanf(val,"%f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f", &xn[k], &yn[k], &zn[k], &ns_ux[k], &ns_uy[k], &ns_uz[k], &l[k], &b[k], &ns[k]);
        float u=0.;


        do {
            u=u+step;
            printf("%f\t%f\n" ,u,radial);

            x_comp=xn[k]+u*ns_ux[k];
            y_comp=yn[k]+u*ns_uy[k];
            z_comp=zn[k]+u*ns_uz[k];
            radial=pow((x_comp*x_comp+y_comp*y_comp+z_comp*z_comp),0.5);
        }while (radial <10.5);   
        if(u >= 1.0 && z_comp >= -3.0 && z_comp <= 3.0){
            int_val=1.0; // ring's width is only 1 unit
        }
        else if(u < 1.0 && z_comp >= -3.0 && z_comp <= 3.0) {
            int_val=u-step;
        }
        else {
            int_val=0.;
        }
        fprintf(fp, "%f\t%f\t%f\t%f\t%f\t%f\t%f\t%f\t%f\t%f\t%f\n",xn[k], yn[k], zn[k], ns[k], l[k], b[k], radial,z_comp,u,u/step, int_val);
    }

    return 0.;
}
```

Comment: a simple sketch would help to understand what you are trying to do

Comment: This is a pictorial representation of my program. 

The Sun and the ring/sources are not in the same plane. 


  [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/WvDKh.png

Comment: To get the geometry straight: the way I understand it, your ring is *not* a torus, but instead is a cylinder of radius 10.5 with a concentric cylinder of radius 9.5 cut out from it, where both cylinders have height 6. Is that right?

Comment: That is right. This ring is more like a hollow cylinder with inner and outer radii 9.5 and 10.5, respectively. The height is 6 units.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have some trouble combining your text with your code. Looking at the code, I see a point at `(xn, yn, zn)` and a ray emanating from that point in the direction `(ns_ux, ns_uy, ns_uz)`. I take it that you want to know when and where that ray intersects your ring.

Currently you do some pretty nasty loop to find even one point of intersection. Let's make that more elegant. You are looking for some `u` such that `sqrt(x_comp²+y_comp²+z_comp²)=10.5`. This is asking for a point where a ray intersects a sphere, so if you want a cylinder here you'd probably want to drop one of the three coordinates. I'll stick with the sphere for now, but that's easy to adapt.

The first thing to do with that equation is to square both sides: `x_comp²+y_comp²+z_comp²=10.5²`. Now you can interpret that sum of squares as a dot product of a vector `v` with itself: `v∙v = 10.5²`. But that vector `v` is in fact the position `n` plus `u` times some vector `ns_u?` which I'll call `s`, so you have `(n + u*s)∙(n + u*s)=10.5²`. Now you can make use of the fact that the distributive law can be applied to the dot product since it's bilinear. So you can also write this as

```
(n∙n - 10.5²) + (2n∙s)u + (s∙s)u² = 0
```

This is a quadratic equation in `u`, which you can solve using the quadratic formula. In code you'd have

```c
nn = xn*xn + yn*yn + zn*zn;
ns = xn*sn_ux + yn*sn_uy + zn*sn_uz;
ss = sn_ux*sn_ux + sn_uy*sn_uy + sn_uz*sn_uz;
r = 10.5;
a = ss;
b = 2*ns;
c = nn - r*r;
d = b*b - 4*a*c;
if (d < 0) {
  // doesn't intersect sphere of radius r at all, but passes outside.
} else if (d == 0) {
  // tangential to sphere, numerically extremely unlikely
  // so you might want to merge this case with the one below.
} else {
  // two points of intersection, parametrized by u1 and u2.
  sqrtd = sqrt(d);
  u1 = (-b+sqrtd)/(2*a);
  u2 = (-b-sqrtd)/(2*a);
}
```

The above intersects a *line* with a sphere. If you want a ray, you'd restrict yourself to solutions `u≥0`. You might want to perform the same computation for the smaller radius. A ray which intersects the larger sphere in two points but the smaller not at all would pass through the area between these two spheres only once. All of this assumes full spheres; you'll still have to apply that thickness constraint to see where the ray passes outside the height of the ring. I can't provide any more detail on that since I haven't fully understood your problem in this respect, but I hope that the above will help you enough to tackle that on your own. If you want a cylinder instead of a sphere, simply drop all `z` components from the above computation.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help ! I was definitely making it more complicated than it was. Now the problem is that I am unable to understand the significance of negative values of 'u'. Basically, the net path length should be absolute difference in the 'u' values of two cylinders with radii 10.5 and 9.5. Therefore, my net u should not be more than the difference between these two radii, but it does not work out.

Comment: u<0 represents a point before the beginning of your ray, if you are considering rays. For lines it probably has no special significance. But since I still don't fully understand your problem, I can't say more about this. Regarding the net amount: Consider two concentric circles of radius 9.5 resp. 10.5. A line which is tangent to the inner circle (i.e. touches it in a single point) will pass through the outer circle for far more than one unit of length. 4*sqrt(5)≈8.94 units of length, to be precise. If you go to 3D, and have one point at z=-3 and one at z=3, then you even get 2*sqrt(29)≈10.77.

Comment: My problem has an inclined ring with a certain width (1 unit) and a certain height (6 units) in space. If a place a source at a random position around that ring, I would like to calculate the length of the intercept made by the line drawn from that source towards my line of sight.  I did not think about the tangent scenario, but when I plot it, it makes sense. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: What if I have any of these sources lying in between 9.5 and 10.5 units ? I seem to not understand the logic whether how it will calculate with varying step size from 9.5 to 10.5.